# Executable of "Open with" dialog on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

How can I open the "Open with" dialog in Windows from command line and other programs? Something like `openwith.exe myfile` or `explorer.exe --openwith-dialog myfile`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Open with" dialog can be opened from the command line as follows :

```
Rundll32 Shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL any-file-name.ext
```

Note that the file-name is not checked for existence before the execution
of the dialog, so if the file doesn't exist the "not found" error message
will only arrive afterward.

Comment: Only `Rundll32 Shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL C:\full-path\any-file-name.ext` works for me on Windows 7, but not `Rundll32 Shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL any-file-name.ext` (even when being in `C:\full-path\`). Is that normal?

Comment: It's possibly true for Windows 7, since I only tested it on Windows 10.

Comment: How do you know this, where are things like `OpenAs_RunDLL` documented/described/listed?

Comment: Personal knowledge based on many sources, using google for the small details.

Comment: Works even with (unescaped) spaces in fully qualified path to a file e.g. `RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL d:\bat\odds and ends\square [brackets]\my list.txt`…

Comment: Source: http://vb.mvps.org/tips/shellcpl.txt